# How to show 2 cannot be totally ramified in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6},\sqrt{10})$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to show that 2 cannot be totally ramified in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6},\sqrt{10})$. I know that it is totally ramified in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{10})$ since $2O_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})}=(2,\sqrt{6})^2$ and similarly $2O_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{10})}=(2,\sqrt{10})^2$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It does totally ramify. In fact, it's easy to see that it totally ramifies in every subextension, and thus if it didn't ramify in $K:=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6},\sqrt{10})$ this would imply that $\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ would be cyclic of prime order (for then it's Galois group can be shown to have no non-trivial subgroups). ARe you sure you're reading the problem correctly?

Comment: You have just proven that it is totally ramified, since in a compositum of disjoint field extensions the ramification indices multiply.

Comment: @Alex B. don't you need to assume that their discriminats are coprime to make such a strong claim?

Comment: @AlexB. Dear Alex, This is not true in general.  E.g. $\mathbb Q(i)$ and $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-5})$ are both (totally) ramified at $2$, but their compositum is not totally ramified at $2$ (since e.g. it contains $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{5})$, which is unram. at $2$).  Regards,

Comment: @Alex and Matt: you are both absolutely right, of course, and I was being silly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, $2$ does totally ramify in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6},\sqrt{10})$.

There are various ways to see this. Here is a nice one:

> **Theorem:** Suppose that $L/K$ is a finite Galois extension of number fields. Suppose that $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime of $\mathcal{O}_K$ which totally ramifies in every proper subextension of $L/K$, but does not totally ramify in $L$. Then, $\text{Gal}(L/K)\cong \mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ for some prime $q$.

Roughly, the reason is as follows. Take the inertia field $E$ of some prime $\mathfrak{P}$ over $\mathfrak{p}$. Note then that $E=L$. Indeed, let $\mathfrak{q}=\mathfrak{P}\cap \mathcal{O}_E$. Assume that $E\subsetneq L$ then, note that by assumption $e(\mathfrak{q}\mid\mathfrak{p})=[E:K]$ and by definition of the inertia field we have that $e(\mathfrak{P}\mid\mathfrak{q})=[L:E]$. Then, we have that $e(\mathfrak{P}\mid\mathfrak{p})=[L:K]$ contradictory to assumption. So, $E=L$ as desired. So, now suppose that $K\subseteq M\subsetneq L$ is any proper subextension of $L/K$. Then, by assumption

$$[M:K]=e(\mathfrak{P}\cap\mathcal{O}_M\mid \mathfrak{p})$$

but since $M\subseteq E=L$ we know that $e(\mathfrak{P}\cap\mathcal{O}_M\mid\mathfrak{p})=1$ and so $[M:K]=1$ or $M=K$. Thus, we see that $\text{Gal}(L/K)$ has no non-trivial proper subgroups, which trivially implies that $\text{Gal}(L/K)\cong\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ for some prime $q$ as desired.

So, how does this help in our case? Well $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6},\sqrt{10})/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois, whose only proper subextensions are $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6}),\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{10})$, and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{15})$. Note that $2$ ramifies in all of these (since all of their discriminants are even), but for quadratic extensions ramifying is the same thing as totally ramifying and so $2$ totally ramifies in every proper subextension of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6},\sqrt{10})$.

So, by our theorem, if $2$ did not ramify in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6},\sqrt{10})$ then $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6},\sqrt{10})/\mathbb{Q})$ would be cyclic of prime order, which it clearly is not.

Comment: Dear Alex, I might just not be thinking clearly, but the first sentence of your argument makes more sense to me if you replace "decomposition field" by "inertia field". Also, don't you mean $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{15)}$ rather than $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{30})$? Otherwise, nice answer! Regards,

Comment: @MattE Maybe I am also not thinking clear, but why is not the inertia field--this is one where all ramification occurs above it. Also, why is it $\sqrt{15}$? Isn't the third subfield of a biquadratic extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b})$ just $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{ab})$? So, in our case we'd get $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2^2\cdot 3\cdot 5})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{30})$? Anyways, thanks :)

Comment: Dear Alex, I think the assertion $e(\mathfrak B | \mathfrak q) = [L:E]$ presumes that $E$ is the inertia field, whereas you write "Take the decomposition field $E$" (and the decomposition field might allow some extension of residue field as well as ramification).  Also, isn't $\sqrt{2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5} = 2 \sqrt{3\cdot 5} = 2 \sqrt{15}$?  (Sorry, I realize these are pretty minor points, and it's quite possible that I'm confused on both of them.) Cheers,

Comment: @MattE Haha, I see now. I thought it was the inertia field, and you were arguing that it should be decomposition--I didn't see it was *I* who had written decomposition in lieu of inertia. I'll fix that. Also, you're correct--I never claimed to be good with numbers :). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

For a prime $\mathfrak{p}$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6},\sqrt{10})$ above $2$, let $I$ be the inertia group and $F$ the inertia field.

From basic ramification theory, $|I|=e_{\mathfrak{p}/2}$ and $2$ does not ramify in $F|\mathbb{Q}$.

We will prove $|I|=e_{\mathfrak{p}/2}=4$.

Suppose $|I|=2$. Then $F$ is a proper subextension, so it must be one of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6}), \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{10})$ or $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{15})$. These have discriminants $24$, $40$ and $60$ respectively, so $2$ ramifies in $F|\mathbb{Q}$ (absurd).

Finally, suppose $|I|=1$. This means $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6},\sqrt{10})$ and that $2$ does not ramify in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6},\sqrt{10})$. This is clearly absurd, since we saw that $2$ ramifies in the intermediate extensions, so it necessarily ramifies in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6},\sqrt{10})$.